# How do I get my Android to turn on?

Tags: boot-loop, motorola

I have a Motorola Turbo 2 Android. It won't turn on. It just stays on the Power By Android screen. I have tried turning it on by holding the volume up and power buttons. The screen shots up but I get lost at this point. It does not give me any option to start.

Now going from the Powered By Android screen... on and off.

What must I do to turn it on?

Might I be over charging it?

Comment: Hold down the power button for a while! It'll turn on. Comment back `@owlswipe` if that doesn't help.

Comment: I tried that several times. It did not work.

Comment: Next step: go into recovery mode and clear your cache. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your phone is soft-bricked. You'll need to hard reset it.

- Begin by switching off the device by holding down the Power key for a short while.
- In the next step press and hold **Volume Down + Power button** *simultaneously* for a few seconds.
- Press the Volume Down to select option "Recovery", and press the Power button to confirm.
- When the Android bot shows up on the screen, hold down the **Volume Up** for a couple of seconds.
- While holding the **Volume Up** hold down the **Power key** and after a short while release all buttons.
- Afterwards press **Volume Down** to choose "***wipe data/factory reset***", and then push the **Power key** to confirm.
- Select "***Yes--delete all user data***". Use **Volume Down button** to scroll and **Power key** to select.
- To restart the tablet, select "**reboot system now**".

Your phone should boot normally.

Note that after a hard reset, the first boot takes several minutes, so be patient.

Please comment down if something goea wrong.

Comment: Will I use all my contacts in my phone if I do the "Yes--delete all user data"?

Comment: It depends on where you have saved them. Do you have a Google backup for your contacts?

Comment: @SharePointNY Try doing what esQmo said except do a wipe of your system cache (which won't delete your data like esQmo's plan will) instead of a deletion of all user data. Clearing your system cache should allow the phone to boot up.

Comment: I am trying the directions above. It's not working yet.

Comment: @SharePoinNY Where are you at?

Comment: This is so frustrating. I was just at my Android phone store. I showed the guy the problem. He said it's dead. I should get a new phone through my insurance. He did not try any of the restarts you suggested. So I did a restart to factory mode. NOW IT'S STARTING! Should I just keep the phone or get the refurbished one?

Comment: I can't tell whether you should or shouldn't, it depends to you now. You can mark this answer as accepted of the solution worked for you.